# Analysis of grayscale image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a grayscale image of 128*500 pixels. I need to analyse the image and find out if it follows any particular distribution, like Weibull or Lognormal or K-distribution. I need help as to how to analyse the image?
Can I use windowed Fourier transform for this image? If so how?
Help me with specific tutorials.

Comment: Find out if **what** follows a particular distribution? The intensity values, the scale of contrasts, something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Junuxx says it is a bit hard to answer you question. But whatever `probability match` you want to check [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34943) `MATLAB Exchange Function` can come in handy. I have used it a lot myself.

What does it do? --> Well the name of it is `Fit all valid parametric probability distributions to data` and I personally think that it is quite self-explanatory. ;)

Read [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/02/10/finding-the-best/) related post on the specific function.

Hope it helps!